# ` (strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0) ` in find LongestCommonPrefix

Tags: java

I read such a solution to LongestCommonPrefix

[Longest Common Prefix - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/solution/)

[image]

```
 public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    if (strs.length == 0) return "";
    String prefix = strs[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++)
        while (strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0) {
            prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
            if (prefix.isEmpty()) return "";
        }        
    return prefix;
}
```

As for `while (strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0)`, if `prefix` is not empty, the expression will constantly return True;

How could conclude that `prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);`, I assumed the `while (strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0)` did nothing.

Comment: "As for while (strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0), if prefix is not empty, the expression will constantly return True" - no it won't, because `prefix` is changed within the body of the loop, and if it's ever empty, the code returns. I'm not sure what you're asking here - could you clarify your question please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of this algorithm is:

1. first assume the first word is the `prefix`, and then we will check
   whether `prefix` is all other word's prefix.
2. if `strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0` means it is not start with `prefix`. 
   So we should cut down the prefix a little bit (remove the last 
   character), that is: `prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);`
3. we continuously do this, util all the words checked, or the prefix has
   been cutted to `''` (that is why it is called `Horizontal scanning`)

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: lol, `strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0` is `not strs[i].startswith(prefix)`, save hours to read java documentations.

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain it in details. actually it means: if prefix is not in str, it return -1, or it will return the index. so if `strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0`, it means `index ==-1` or `index > 0`, just the opposite of `startwith`

Comment: actually java has `startsWith` api, you can try this, I think it also works.

Answer (score 4):

This code basically takes the first string out of a list of strings

```
String prefix = strs[0];
```

And removes the last character from this string

```
prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
```

Until the next string **contains** this substring.

```
while (strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0)
```

This is repeated for every string in the input array.

```
for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++)
```

If the algorithm has successfully verified that `strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0` for the every input string, `prefix` is the longest substring but not the longest common prefix.

As you already mentioned in the comments instead of checking for `strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0` you should use `strs[i].startsWith(prefix)` as condition for the while-loop. This way you should get the common **prefix**.